# pull stream from rtmp server and extract images to do some deep learning prediction then stream the images to rtmp server again

Tags: ffmpeg, images, streaming

Hi，I am using ffmpeg to stream  my video to rtmp server  in PCA,and extract the  frame  from the rtmp stream with opencv's VideoCapture and do some process with these images and then re-stream the images to the rtmp server in order with python pipe like

`ffmpeg_command = ['ffmpeg',
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-vcodec','rawvideo',
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
            '-s', "{}x{}".format(1920,1080),
            '-i', '-',
            '-c:v', 'libx264',
            '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
            '-preset', 'ultrafast',
            '-tune','zerolatency',
            '-b:v','2000k',
            '-f', 'flv', 
            "rtmp:*********"]
ffmpeg_720 = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=sp.PIPE,preexec_fn = os.setsid)`

when I watch the second stream ，the video is not smooth，but the first one  is smooth. Is it caused by slow transcoding speed or  something else. Could someone know how to fix this. Welcome any suggestions！！Thanks.

Comment: Any real-time video processing (with OpenCV or anything else) is going to introduce delay. It also isn't clear whether this is purely a processing problem or simply a slow server connection. Collecting a certain number of images before sending them back out might help but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks for your answer，I read the information on the Internet that the normal delay of RTMP is about 1 second to 3 seconds, but the delay I get is about half a minute under the condition of good network  even if I have used the option of x264 '- tune zeroity' and '- preset ultra fast' on the command line of ffmpeg, what's the matter